# kprobe not working for some functions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kprobe, jprobe

I am trying to use kprobe to track `handle_pte_fault` function calls in linux kernel. I can probe `handle_mm_fault` but when I try to probe `handle_pte_dault`, kprobe's handler for `handle_pte_fault` doesn't print anything.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221631/kprobe-handler-not-getting-triggered-for-specific-function?rq=1) I figured that i can't probe a function which is inline and also maybe static. So, I changed the definition of the `handle_pte_fault` function as following and recompiled the kernel.

From:

```
static int handle_pte_fault(struct vm_fault *vmf)
```

to:

```
noinline int handle_pte_fault(struct vm_fault *vmf)
```

I also added following to make sure `handle_pte_fault` symbol exists

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(handle_pte_fault);
```

Still I am not able to track/probe handle_pte_fault function. Any help or explanation. Does it mean kprobe will only work for some random functions?

I am using kernel v4.13.

Below is the kernel module code for the kprobe that i am using:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/version.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/kprobes.h>

static struct kprobe kp;
static const char *probed_func = "handle_pte_fault";

static unsigned int counter = 0;

int Pre_Handler(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs){
        printk("Pre_Handler: counter=%u\n",counter++);
        return 0;
}

void Post_Handler(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long flags){
        printk("Post_Handler: counter=%u\n",counter++);
}


int myinit(void)
{
        printk("module inserted\n ");

        kp.pre_handler = Pre_Handler;
        kp.post_handler = Post_Handler;
        kp.addr = (kprobe_opcode_t *)kallsyms_lookup_name(probed_func);

        register_kprobe(&kp);

        return 0;
}

void myexit(void)
{
        unregister_kprobe(&kp);
        printk("module removed\n ");
}

module_init(myinit);
module_exit(myexit);
MODULE_AUTHOR("User1");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("KPROBE MODULE");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: What is return value of `register_kprobe()` call? It should be an indicator whether setting kprobe was successfull or not.

Comment: Yes, the return value of `register_kprobe` should always be checked. Apart from that, you could also check if `kallsyms_lookup_name` returned a correct address of `handle_pte_fault`. Besides, take a look at the messages in dmesg after you have loaded your module. If there are error messages there, it could help understand what is going wrong.

Comment: It actually works, I was making mistakes in rebooting by using older compiled image. Once i reboot with correct image, it works fine. Thanks for the help.